# Node doesn't display character, networkx

Tags: python

I have written an sample code to check the frequency of each text available in a given file.
Please find the code below

```
#Frequency of Given Search Key term from files
import os
import plistlib
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = str(raw_input("Enter the filename : "))
fp = open(filename,'r')
buffer1 = fp.read()
fp.close()
fp = open(filename,'r')
words = list(fp.read().split())
word = list(set(words))
fp.close()
G = nx.DiGraph()
for eachword1 in word:
    cnt = buffer1.count(eachword1)
    G.add_edge(eachword1,cnt,weight=0.9,color='blue',size=300)
    print eachword1,"occurred",cnt," times"
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
</i>
```

Where I can get the graph, but no text in the node. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You have drawn the graph, but haven't requested the names of the nodes.  To draw the node labels, use draw_networkx_labels in the networkx package.

Here's your code modified to have labels on the nodes: "positions" should probably be set using something other than "spring" if you want things to be pretty:

```
import os
import plistlib
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = str(raw_input("Enter the filename : "))
fp = open(filename,'r')
buffer1 = fp.read()
fp.close()
fp = open(filename,'r')
words = list(fp.read().split())
word = list(set(words))
fp.close()
G = nx.DiGraph()
for eachword1 in word:
    cnt = buffer1.count(eachword1)
    G.add_edge(eachword1,cnt,weight=0.9,color='blue',size=300)
    print eachword1,"occurred",cnt," times"
positions = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G,positions)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,positions)
plt.show()
```

Clear?

Comment: I have added nx.draw_networkx_lables(g,nx.sprint_layout(G)) above nx.draw() but not luck, code will be appericated